# Compute absolute differences between conditions' values across times with dplyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I would like to compare the absolute differences between conditions across time. For example, here I have two conditions (A & B) and each condition has it own value across time (1:3).

```
df <- data.frame("condition" =c("A","B","A","A","B","B"), "time" = c(1,1,2,3,2,3) ,"value" = c(-2,3,5,1,1,6))
```

How can I create a new condition (C) as the absolute difference between condition A & B across time with dplyr?

```
expected_outcome <- data.frame("condition" =c("A","B","A","A","B","B","Diff","Diff","Diff"), "time" = c(1,1,2,3,2,3,1,2,3) ,"value" = c(-2,3,5,1,1,6,1,4,5))
```

In order to create a plot with those 3 conditions? for example:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=time,y=value,color= condition)) +stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="line")
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modulo column order:

```
df %>% spread(condition, value) %>%
    mutate(Diff=abs(abs(A) - abs(B))) %>%
    gather(condition, value, -time)
```

Answer (score 0):

`aggregate` will do the trick:

```
dif <- aggregate(df$value, list(df$time), function(x) abs(diff(abs(x))))
dif <- data.frame(condition = "Diff", time = dif[,1], value = dif[,2])
dif <- rbind(df, dif)
dif

   condition time value
1         A    1    -2
2         B    1     3
3         A    2     5
4         A    3     1
5         B    2     1
6         B    3     6
7      Diff    1     1
8      Diff    2     4
9      Diff    3     5
```